# Как узнать об изменении таблицы БД

Tags: c#, база-данных

Здравствуйте.

Я выполняю запрос к базе данных (MSSQL/ACCESS), получаю данные.
Если кто-то изменил эти данные после моего запроса, я об этом не узнаю.
Как приложение может об этом сразу же узнать?
Вариант: каждые *х* секунд обновлять запрос - как-то не очень хороший.

Может, есть другие способы?
Например, "вконтакте" новости и остальное подгружает в реальном времени - он делает запросы каждые несколько секунд или есть другой механизм?
(моя программа не веб - C# WPF)

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Для получения уведомлений от MS SQL в ADO.NET есть класс [SqlDependency](http://bit.ly/YOtazQ).
Так же можешь посмотреть [Уведомление о запросах в SQL Server](http://bit.ly/YOtrTn)

Answer (score 3):

Очень подробно о всех способах отслеживания изменений указаны в [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559581/how-to-notify-a-windows-servicec-of-a-db-table-changesql-2005) на stackoverflow.com.
Из наиболее употребляемых способов, можно выделить

1. уведомления со стороны БД, основан на [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.90).aspx)(смотри ответ [MaLS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11230/mals)). Примеры [здесь](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/) и [здесь](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring).
2. долбить нужные таблицы базы каждые несколько секунд и сверять [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258245%28SQL.80%29.aspx) и пример описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36/check-for-changes-to-an-sql-server-table).

Выбирай то, что подходит больше тебе. Уведомления требуют больше трудозатрат, но элегантнее, а постоянно опрашивать базу реализовать не составит особого труда, но врядли подойдет для больших баз.