# Взять данные из БД Sql Server

Tags: c#

Есть `datatable`, который берёт данные из БД **sql server**. Допустим, программа запущена. Если я добавлю строку БД , то `datatable` не обновляется. Посоветовали `SqlDependency`. Как сделать чтобы `datatable` автоматический обновлялся, даже если программа запущена?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/198822/196257

Comment: @Monk `checksum` прочитал, что то понятно, что то нет. Можете объяснить конкретно ,пожалуйста, что это такое?(впервые слышу такое)

Comment: Как можно связывать `обновление` и `cheksum`?

Comment: Откуда вы вообще взяли про checksum? Я явно дал ссылку на sqldependency

Comment: @Monk спасибо за инф! Как мне теперь включить `добавленную` запись в `datatable`?

Comment: У него просто программа отслеживает, если есть изменение. А мне надо автоматический обновлять существующий `datatable`. По моему разница есть.